# Delete default signature in Outlook and replace with content from doc/htm file

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

My workplace has introduced an draconian new uniform signature across the entire business which looks absolutely repulsive, and I can't in good conscience email clients without having to manually change it every single time.

I'm assuming it's being created via a macro that runs at start up. I'd like to set up a macro that I can activate from the ribbon that deletes the default signature that is in place when Outlook starts, and replace it with a new signature that is sourced (including formatting) from either a doc or a html file.

I've been searching for a couple of hours and can't find any macro code that either a) deletes a signature or b) allows for the creation of a new one by way of data from another file.

Can VB do what I'm looking for?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried changing the default signature for your email account?  You should be able to set that once, and it will remain as set.  Please verify that you have tried that solution and that it doesn't work.

Comment: If above doesn't work record a macro. Try Ctrl + End and Shift + Up arrows to select then replace. Alt + T, M, R.

Comment: Does the policy override the default signature, or deny access to the signatures dialog?

Comment: Speaking from a company point of view and dealing with this type of stuff in the past myself, surely if they want you to use a particular corporate signature *(probably being enforced by a mail gateway of some sort)* then should you be trying to override it? Plus if you see it as such an issue surely you should raise it with the company?

Comment: Did you find a solution? And was it only a Windows thing or also OSX / MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the default signature for your e-mail account with the Outlook Options, take a look at

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

You will find the HTML files containing your signatures. Edit it directly...

Comment: Depends on how the permissions are set, may even find if mandatory profiles are used this is pointless.

Comment: That's right, but if you have no permission on that folder, there is really nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new signature, that way you only need to select it from a drop-down menu in the ribbon, and the policies that enforce the default will not see the custom one.